# Why does GMAIL removes inline style from my HTML email?

Tags: html, gmail, html-email

So I thought I am going to create an Html email in Gmail, it is going to be easy...
I have read a few articles about it, when creating email it can only have inline style and nothing in the header. ok.

I open gmail..compose email...enter some random text...select the text...right click on it...inspect...edit html...and paste my html source code into where my random text was. Voila! It looks fine. But when I send the email (or just save it as draft and view it) **my inner divs background becomes the background of the outer div as well, it overlaps it.**
I have tried to paste the whole source code, I have tried to paste 
`<body>...</body>`

and I have also tried to paste in only code from the most outer div. 
**Why does gmail remove my style?**

[image: entered html code]
[image: saved in draft html code]
This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
 <div style="color: #FFFFFF; padding:30px;">
  <div style="border-radius: 25px; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529088363398-8efc64a0eb95?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=179403fa836a063432aec8ccc04ee248&auto=format&fit=crop&w=424&q=80); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; height: 400px; color: #ACA394; text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000; display: -webkit-box; display: -moz-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; align-items: center; width: 100%">
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);">
     <h1><b>Title</b> Subtitle</h1>
     <h2>Some text</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't try to send responsive from Gmail editor. Sign up to something free like MailChimp and add inline style to your headings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is because Gmail doesn't support `flex`.[supported CSS attributes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Gmail doesn't accept all types of CSS. However, [this link](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1500-using-flexbox-in-an-email) might be of some help to you. Good luck!

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you